# SPFx as Teams tab - pop out tab not working

Tags: spfx, microsoft-teams

Running an SPFx webpart as a Tab in a Team.
The button "pop out tab" is available, when you click on it the tab is popped out but nothing is loading.
Anyone know if this is a confirmed bug?
[image]